# Cannot print right result for certain conditions

Tags: java

I created a Java program which takes user input as an integer array and prints any duplicate values in that array along with their indices. For example, user enters 5 to be the array size, then enters 5 numbers, such as 1, 1, 1, 1, and 1. Program should print: Duplicate number: 1 Duplicate number's index: 1 Duplicate number: 1 Duplicate number's index: 2 Duplicate number: 1 Duplicate number's index: 3 Duplicate number: 1 Duplicate number's  index: 4. If there are no duplicates, program prints "no duplicates" The program works as it should...except that it prints "no duplicates" even if there are duplicates.

I tried numerous things, such as using a Boolean flag (if duplicates found, then true, then print result), also setting it to false, inserting more if conditions, putting "no duplicates" print.out in different places within curly brackets, but nothing works. If I put "no duplicates" print.out outside the loop, then it prints even if there are duplicates. If I put "no duplicates" print.out as part of "no duplicates found condition" then multiple "no duplicates" are printed out, since it is part of loop. I tried debugging but can't see where issue with my code is. Please help.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i, j;
System.out.println("This program lets you enter an array of numbers, and then tells you if any of the numbers "
        + "are duplices, and what the duplicates' indices are. \nPlease enter your desired array size: ");
int arraySize = sc.nextInt();
while (arraySize <= 0) {
    System.out.println(arraySize + " is not a valid number. \nPlease enter your desired array size: ");
    arraySize = sc.nextInt();
    continue;
}
int[] arrayList = new int[arraySize];
System.out.print("Please enter your array values: ");
for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    arrayList[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
boolean duplicates = false;
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < arrayList.length; j++) {
        if (arrayList[i] == arrayList[j]) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate number: " + arrayList[i]);
            System.out.println("Duplicate number's index: " + j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `duplicates` flag which you initialize to `false`, but never set to `true` when there are duplicates. Assuming you have a simple `if` after your `for` loop (and if you don't you need one), it *should* look something like

```
boolean duplicates = false;
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < arrayList.length; j++) {
        if (arrayList[i] == arrayList[j]) {
            duplicates = true; // <-- Add this.
            System.out.println("Duplicate number: " + arrayList[i]);
            System.out.println("Duplicate number's index: " + j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!duplicates) {
    System.out.println("no duplicates");
}
```

Comment: That worked! In one of my attempts, I actually had set flag as true within if statements, but had not included that !duplicates condition at the very end. I learned good java today :)